# vue.js обращение к массиву по индексу

Tags: vue.js

привет необходимо в переменную team записать элемент из массива но в vue.js  обращение по индексу так не работает(написано он офф сайте)
есть функция

```
vue.set(array, index, value);
```

но это записать в массив по индексу а мне надо получить

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items:[
            {
                id: 4454654654,
                title: 1124
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 45
            },
            {
                id: 22,
                title: 11
            },
            {
                id: 46,
                title: 1546
            },
            {
                id: 44545,
                title: 14564
            },
            {
                id: 4890,
                title: 1456890
            },
            {
                id: 4880890,
                title: 180
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                title: 1
            }
        ],
        team: this.items[0].title
    }
})
```

то есть типа так  `team: this.items[0].title`

Comment: Так в чём вопрос ? и зачем вам связывание в массиве элементы , и так же отдельно , почему не пользоваться чем что в массиве ?*

Comment: я хочу в две переменные записать значения из  элемента  массива и их вывестия же писао выше что обращение по индексу нету

Comment: Не. я понял задачу , я просто не пойму зачем так нужно , если такого нет в функционале , да по сути и не нужно ... Извините не могу представить задачу

Comment: не я хочу по нажатию на кнопку показывать слд элемент маасива и при нажатиина другую  предвдущий ну как както так    типа будт счетчик i которв будет инкрементирвоатся  и будет подстаалтсяв индекс

Comment: Переменной дать значение 0 , и при клике делать инкримент и дикримент этой переменной, и после v-for , сделать проверка v-if="index == //Ваша переменная"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример на [JSFDD](https://jsfiddle.net/zww3g7yh/1/)

```
var a = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    arr:[1,2,3,4,5],
    count:0
  },
  // определяйте методы в объекте `methods`
  methods: {
    clickOne: function () {
      this.count--;
    },
    clickTwo: function () {
      this.count++;
    }
  }
})



<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item,index) in arr">
      <span v-if="index == count"> {{ item }} </span>
    </div>


    <button v-on:click="clickOne()">Назад</button>
    <button v-on:click="clickTwo()">Вперед</button>
</div>
```